# PLS-00103 sqlplus error on trigger creation

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I tried to compile this code on Oracle sqlplus but it returned some errors.
What i'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_id
BEFORE INSERT ON Area
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
numero AREA.codigo%TYPE;

BEGIN   
    SELECT MAX(CODIGO) INTO numero FROM AREA;
    IF numero < 42
        :NEW.codigo := 42;
    ELSE 
        :NEW.codigo := numero +1;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

SQL> show errors;

```
Errors for TRIGGER CHECK_ID:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
7/3      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the
         following:
         * & - + / at mod lembrete rem then <um expoente (**)> e ou ||
         multiset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the keyword `THEN` on the line

```
    IF numero < 42
```

It should be

```
    IF numero < 42 THEN
```